# Issue with dynamic import and vitest

Tags: node.js, express, vitest

I'm using Vitest to run tests in a Node.js + Express API. I have a problem with my routes: it returns a 404 error only during the first test run, but returns 200 during all subsequent test runs.

Has anyone experienced a similar issue with Vitest or have any ideas on how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for your help and insights!

I've tried to debug the issue and found that the dynamic import is not executed during the first run, but works as expected during the second run. This makes me wonder if the problem is related to the Vitest cache system.

```
import { Express, Router } from 'express';
import fastGlob from 'fast-glob';

export default (app: Express): void => {
  const router = Router();
  app.use('/api', router);

  const files = fastGlob.sync('**/src/main/router/routes/**.routes.ts');

  files.map(async (file: string) => {
    const route = (await import(`../../../${file}`)).default;

    route(router);
  });
};
```

My test file:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { describe, beforeAll, afterAll, it, expect } from 'vitest';

import app from '../../../src/main/config/app';
import datasource from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/helpers/data-source.helper';
import { UserOrmModel } from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/models/user.model';

describe('Account Routes', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await datasource.initialize();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await datasource.getRepository(UserOrmModel).clear();
    await datasource.destroy();
  });

  const makeFakeUserData = () => ({
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john_doe_int@mail.com',
    password: '123456',
    passwordConfirmation: '123456',
  });

  describe('POST /signup', async () => {
    it('should return 200 if valid data is passed', async () => {
      const httpResponse = await request(app)
        .post('/api/signup')
        .send(makeFakeUserData());

      expect(httpResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your route is registered asynchronously without being `await` / `.then` in your code. You might want to consider adding `async` / `await` in your setup code (eg. `beforeAll`). Refer to the example here to allow `await` a setup code: https://vitest.dev/api/#beforeall

Comment: Thanks, @AngYC. Do you have a clue about what I could do in the beforeAll to wait for this?

Comment: Hi @Carlos, I have added an answer and hope it gives you an idea on how you can achieve this

Comment: Thanks, @AngYC. I ended up doing something else here, but I appreciate your help. I haven't tested your solution yet, but I'll do it when I can. I just answered my own question with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Your route is registered asynchronously without being `await` / `.then` in your code. You might want to consider adding `async` / `await` in your setup code (eg. `beforeAll`)

Here's an example / idea on what you can do:

```
import { Express, Router } from 'express';
import fastGlob from 'fast-glob';

async function getRouter() {
  const router = Router();

  const files = fastGlob.sync('**/src/main/router/routes/**.routes.ts');
  await files.map(async (file: string) => {
    const route = (await import(`../../../${file}`)).default;
    route(router);
  });

  return router;
}

export default async (app: Express): Promise<void> => {
  const router = await getRouter();
  app.use('/api', router);
};
```

Test files (Notice the `getApp`):

```js
import request from 'supertest';
import { describe, beforeAll, afterAll, it, expect } from 'vitest';

import { getApp } from '../../../src/main/config/app';
import datasource from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/helpers/data-source.helper';
import { UserOrmModel } from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/models/user.model';

describe('Account Routes', () => {
  let app;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await datasource.initialize();
    app = await getApp();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await datasource.getRepository(UserOrmModel).clear();
    await datasource.destroy();
  });

  const makeFakeUserData = () => ({
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john_doe_int@mail.com',
    password: '123456',
    passwordConfirmation: '123456',
  });

  describe('POST /signup', async () => {
    it('should return 200 if valid data is passed', async () => {
      const httpResponse = await request(app)
        .post('/api/signup')
        .send(makeFakeUserData());

      expect(httpResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with the help of a colleague who suggested these changes:

```
import { Express, Router } from 'express';
import fastGlob from 'fast-glob';

export default (app: Express): Promise<void>[] => {
  const router = Router();
  app.use('/api', router);

  const files = fastGlob.sync('**/src/main/router/routes/**.routes.ts');

  return files.map(async (file: string) => {
    const route = (await import(`../../../${file}`)).default;

    route(router);
  });
};
```

```
import express from 'express';
import setMiddlewares from '../middlewares';
import setRoutes from '../router';

const app = express();

setMiddlewares(app);

const routes = setRoutes(app);

export { app, routes };
```

```
import request from 'supertest';

import { app, routes } from '../../../src/main/config/app';
import datasource from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/helpers/data-source.helper';
import { UserOrmModel } from '../../../src/infra/db/postgres/models/user.model';

describe('Account Routes', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await datasource.initialize();
    await Promise.all(routes);
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await datasource.getRepository(UserOrmModel).clear();
    await datasource.destroy();
  });

  const makeFakeUserData = () => ({
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'john_doe_int@mail.com',
    password: '123456',
    passwordConfirmation: '123456',
  });

  describe('POST /signup', async () => {
    it('should return 200 if valid data is passed', async () => {
      const httpResponse = await request(app)
        .post('/api/signup')
        .send(makeFakeUserData());

      expect(httpResponse.statusCode).toBe(200);
    });
  });
});
```